# Sum of two multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I have a array in JavaScript like this.

```
var arr=
[ 
  ['A'],[1,2,3,4],
  ['A'],[4,3,2,1],
  ['B'],[10,12,3,1],
  ['B'],[1,2,3,4],
  .
  .
  .
  .
  ['AZ'],[1,2,3,4]
]
```

and I want the output to summarize the array like -

```
var output=
[
  ['A'],[5,5,5,5],
  ['B'],[11,14,6,5],
  ['AZ'],[1,2,3,4]
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you missed it after registering, take a [tour], read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] and take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how to most benefit from it.  When asking questions, make sure you provide a clear explanation of what it is you are trying to do-- it is not currently clear from the question. Also, generally you are expected to show what attempts you have made to solve this issue yourself. Please note that SO is not a free coding service-- just dropping a list of requirements in your question and asking for a wholesale solution is unlikely to garner favor for your question. Good luck, happy coding!

Comment: What is the formula you're using? Maybe I can create a loop for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Script

You can use the following script to achieve what you want to do.

```js
const arr = [
  ["A"],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  ["A"],
  [4, 3, 2, 1],
  ["B"],
  [10, 12, 3, 1],
  ["B"],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  ["AZ"],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
];

/**
 * Generator to return key-value pairs with array[i] being the key and array[i+1] being the value
 * @param {Array<any>} array
 */
function* keyValue(array) {
  // make sure we can build pairs (other ways of handling this are also possible)
  if (array.length % 2 !== 0)
    throw new RangeError(
      "Array length must be dividable by 2 without remainder!"
    );
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    yield [array[i], array[i + 1]];
  }
}

// here the created key-value pairs
console.log("Key-value pairs created by keyValue() generator function:");
console.log([...keyValue(arr)]);

// loop over key value pairs and sum up all the individul arrays based on the letter assigned to them
const result = [...keyValue(arr)].reduce((all, [[key], array]) => {
  // if we don't have values for this letter, assing copy of the array to that letter
  if (!all[key]) all[key] = [...array];
  // we have some values for that letter already, sum up each value
  else all[key] = all[key].map((prev, idx) => prev + array[idx]);
  return all;
}, {});
// this would be a "better" result to my mind as there is no point wrapping single string values in arrays
// When using objects the values can easily be accessed in O(1)
console.log(result);

// now transform JS object to array of arrays
console.log("Result:");
const transformed = Object.entries(result).flatMap(([key, value]) => [[key], value]);
console.log(transformed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

> Please note: This implementation assumes that the arrays for a given letter have the same length (as is the case in your example).

#### Explanation

First of all, I use a [generator function](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_sync-generators.html) `keyValue()` to always group two consecutive values in the array (a key and a value) together. One could also do this differently but once you understand how generators work that's an easy and elegant approach, I think. For this demo I just throw an error if the array is not dividable by 2 without remainder, but one could also handle this more gracefully.

Then, using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), I iterate over the array created by using `keyValue()` and for each element in the array I check if I've encountered that value before. If I have not, I create a copy of the array ([for immutablility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)) and assign it to the key i.e. a letter. If I have encountered a certain letter before I add up the values that I have previously saved assigned to that letter with the ones I am currently processing. After iteration all sums are calculated and I have a JavaScript object containing the results.

To my mind, this would be a good output because your output is a bit odd, since there is no point storing single letters in an array or even arrays of arrays. Using a JavaScript object is much more convenient and faster for lookups.

Nevertheless, you can easily deduct your result from the created object using [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).